# php ajax count function is not wroking properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax and php count function, if I used $_SESSION['counter'] in both page then its working good but when I'm using $_POST['counter'] then its not working, please help me where I'm going wrong, This is my code.

Index.php

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click me!" />
<div id="counter" style="color:#F00;"><?php 
    if(isset($_POST['counter'])){   
        $_POST['counter']; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo $_POST['counter'] = 0; 
    } ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'count.php',
        data: {counter: true},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#counter').text(response);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

count.php

```
if(!isset($_POST['counter'])) {
    $_POST['counter'] = 0;
}
if(isset($_POST['counter'])) {
    $_POST['counter']++;
    echo json_encode($_POST['counter']);
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is ajax counter, please

Answer (score 3):

You always pass the same thing, `data: {counter: true},` if you want on each click, counter to increase, you have to store it in form hidden value or as you mentioned in session.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var count = 0;

$('#button').on('click', function(){
    count++;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'count.php',
        data: {counter: count},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#counter').text(response);
        }
    });
});
});
```

**Update:**

And in `count.php` we have to just display `count` and not increase again:

```
if(isset($_POST['counter'])) {
    echo json_encode($_POST['counter']);
}
```

But if your code is depended on server process, I mean if you increase count in the case if something proceded then better increase count in php, and store returned `count` in javascript after successfully calling `ajax` for later use.

**Update 2:**
It's easy, your `count.php` should look something like this:

```
$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST['counter'])) {
    $count = intval($_POST['counter']);
}

/**
 * Here you can increase counter,
 * if you'd like to do it on server side
 */
$count++; 

$response = array(
    'count' => $count,
    'displayText' => 'Counter value: '.$count
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

**And javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var count = 0;

    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        /**
         * So you increase count here or in php
         */
        count++;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'count.php',
            data: {counter: count},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response) {
                count = parseInt(response.count);
                $('#counter').text(response.displayText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @George its working but after click on the 2nd time on the click Me! button its increment in this order 0, 2,3,4... but not showing 1, what is the problem?

Comment: please can you suggest me as you told 'store returned count in javascript', if i want to count in php then how can I return it in javascript because I'm newbie in ajax. :(